# Move/duplicate an element to another place on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row of five boxes. When you click on any except the first one, the clicked box fades out, the ones before it slide to the right, and a new box appears on the far left as the new first element.

1) Instead of prepending the body with the div with classes "primaryfade," "primary," and "box", I'd rather prepend with the element I just clicked without the class "fade-out" but with new classes "primary" and "primary-fade" (while still retaining the class "box").

2) In my fiddle I realize that any box that previously had the class "primary" and then moved to a non-first position no longer triggers the animation if clicked on again. I don't know why that is, but I'd like any element to move back to the first position on click regardless.

I'm sure my jQuery can be written more elegantly. I'm not very experienced with it. This is for proof of concept.

http://jsfiddle.net/q6rtgh79/3/

HTML -

```
<div class="primary box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
```

CSS -

```
body {border:1px solid;}

.box {color:white;font-weight:bold;transition: opacity 1s, background 1s;display:inline-block;width: 40px;height:40px;background: gray;margin-left: 20px;}

.box:first-child {margin:0;}

.box4 {background: pink;}

.allmove .box {transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;transform: translate3d(150%,0,0);}

.allmove .fade-out ~ .box, .primary, .primary ~ .box {
transform: translate(0,0)!important;}

.primary {background:green;}

.fade-out, .primaryfade {opacity: 0;}
```

jQuery -

```
$(function() {                       
$(".box:not(:first-child)").click(function() {  
  $(this).addClass("fade-out"); 

  $(".primary").removeClass("primary");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("body").addClass("allmove");
  }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("body").prepend("<div class=\"primaryfade primary box\">new</div>");
  }, 1500);

  setTimeout(function() {          
    $("div[class*='fade-out']").remove();
  }, 1500);

  setTimeout(function() {
      $("body").removeClass("allmove");
  }, 1500);

  setTimeout(function() {
      $("[class*='primaryfade']").removeClass("primaryfade")
  }, 2000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Agree with Rohan, but to solve you first point of ", I'd rather prepend with the element I just clicked" instead of

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $("body").prepend("<div class=\"primaryfade primary box\">new</div>");
        $("div[class*='fade-out']").remove();
        $("body").removeClass("allmove");
    }, 1500);
```

use

```
var item = $(this);
    setTimeout(function (item) {
       $("body").prepend(item.removeClass('fade-out').addClass('primaryfade').addClass('primary').addClass('box').html('new'));
        $("div[class*='fade-out']").remove();
        $("body").removeClass("allmove");
    }, 1500, item);
```

This will:

- prepend the current item you clicked on
- remove the `fade-out` class
- add the `primary` and `primaryfade` and `box` classes
- update the text to 'new'

Comment: This works. I removed the .html('new') since I need to keep the box's original content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)** for dynamically added boxes like,

```
$(document).on('click',".box:not(:first-child)",function() {
   ....
   ....
});
```

It will solve your second point as well as first issue. See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/q6rtgh79/4/)**

You can merge the animation for 1500 seconds like,

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".box:not(:first-child)", function () {
        $(this).addClass("fade-out");

        $(".primary").removeClass("primary");

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("body").addClass("allmove");
        }, 1000);

        // merge the functions which are called after 1500ms
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("body").prepend("<div class=\"primaryfade primary box\">new</div>");
            $("div[class*='fade-out']").remove();
            $("body").removeClass("allmove");
        }, 1500);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("[class*='primaryfade']").removeClass("primaryfade")
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/q6rtgh79/6/)

Answer (score 1):

use something like this :-

```
$(function() {
    function clickEvent(){  
    $(".box:not(:first-child)").off("click");
    $(".box:not(:first-child)").on("click",function() {  
        console.log('here')
      $(this).addClass("fade-out"); 

      $(".primary").removeClass("primary");

      setTimeout(function() {
        $("body").addClass("allmove");
      }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("body").prepend("<div class=\"primaryfade primary box\">new</div>");
              clickEvent();
      }, 1500);

      setTimeout(function() {          
        $("div[class*='fade-out']").remove();
      }, 1500);

      setTimeout(function() {
          $("body").removeClass("allmove");
      }, 1500);

      setTimeout(function() {
          $("[class*='primaryfade']").removeClass("primaryfade")
      }, 2000);

  });
    }
    clickEvent()
});
```

here is the link  http://jsfiddle.net/q6rtgh79/5/